# CodeIgniter Table Class: Add a Link From a Generated Cell

Tags: codeigniter, anchor, code-generation

I'm using the table class that auto-generates a table for me from an array of data pulled from my database.

**Model**:

```
function get_reports_by_user_id($userid)
{
    return $this->db->get_where('ss2_report',array('userid' => $userid))->result_array();
}
```

**Controller**:

```
function index()
{
    echo $this->table->generate($this->mymodel->get_reports_by_user_id('1234'));
}
```

The controller will eventually be moved to a view when I have it working. This generates the table just fine, but I'd like to add a link to a field. For example, the `id` column that would allow me to link to a page of data for just that report's id. I know I can just output the table the old fashioned way by hand. I can then add whatever links I want, but I'd love to be able to use the auto-generation as much as possible. There's got to be a way to do something as common as linking a table cell. Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**:

User **Java PHP** has it mostly right below. Here's the code that makes it work:

```
function get_reports_by_user_id($userid)
{
    $rows = $this->db->get_where('ss2_report',array('userid' => $userid))->result_array();

    foreach ($rows as $count => $row)
    {
        $rows[$count]['id'] = anchor('report/'.$row['id'],$row['id']);
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

I just needed to replace the value in the original array with the anchor text version.

Comment: Instead of using $count, you could do: foreach ($rows as $count=>$row) and $count will be auto-incremented with each iteration

Comment: thanks again, updated the code with that improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way is, in the function `get_reports_by_user_id()` , you would loop through all the results and add the `<a href>` tag to the ids. Something like this:

```
function get_reports_by_user_id($userid)
{
   $rows=$this->db->get_where('ss2_report',array('userid' => $userid))->result_array();
   foreach ($rows as $row)
   {
     $row->id=anchor('site.com/some_controller/some_function/'.$row->id,$row->id);
   }
   return $rows;
}
```

I don't use CodeIgniter's database library so I'm not sure of what format it returns `$rows` in, but the code above should give you the general idea of what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, that's mostly right. The only change I had to make was as posted in my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

One idea might be to do something like..

```
foreach ($row in $this->mymodel->get_reports_by_user_id('1234'))
{
    $row->id = anchor(site_url(array('report', 'user', $row->id)), $row->id);
    $this->table->add_row($row);
}
$this->table->generate();
```